# .equal not working in else if statement

Tags: java, string, if-statement, applet, comparison

I am creating a game where I have created a string that contains one letter and want something to happen if the button I clicked while the random letter has been selected. The problem is with the `.equals()`, I have also tried to change the `String` array variable to a `char` array and use `==` with the same issues:

```
public class JeuxMemoire extends Applet implements ActionListener {
    Button start;
    Button end;

    Button un= new Button("q");
    Button deux= new Button("w");
    Button trois= new Button("e");
    Button quatre= new Button("r");
    Button cinq= new Button("t");
    Button six= new Button("y");
    Button sept= new Button("u");
    Button huit= new Button("i");
    Button neuf= new Button("o");
    Button dix= new Button("p");
    Button onze= new Button("a");
    Button douze= new Button("s");
    Button treize= new Button("d");
    Button quatorze= new Button("f");
    Button quinze= new Button("g");
    Button seize= new Button("h");

    int scur = 0;
    String[] num = {"q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y", "u", "i", "o", "p", "a", "s", "d", "f", "g", "h"};
    Label score;
    Label timer = new Label("Lettre: ") ;
    Label lettre = new Label("temps: ");

    public void RestartGame()
    {
        start.setEnabled(true);
        un.setEnabled(false);
        deux.setEnabled(false);
        trois.setEnabled(false);
        quatre.setEnabled(false);
        cinq.setEnabled(false);
        six.setEnabled(false);
        sept.setEnabled(false);
        huit.setEnabled(false);
        neuf.setEnabled(false);
        dix.setEnabled(false);
        onze.setEnabled(false);
        douze.setEnabled(false);
        treize.setEnabled(false);
        quatorze.setEnabled(false);
        quinze.setEnabled(false);
        seize.setEnabled(false);
        scur = 0;

    }

    public String populateStringArray()
    {

        int ran =  (int) (Math.random() * 15);
        //System.out.println(ran);
        return num[ran];
    }

    public void init(){

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        Font policeApplet = new Font("ComicSans", Font.BOLD, 20);
        this.setFont(policeApplet);


    start = new Button ("Commence");
    start.addActionListener(this);

    Panel superior = new Panel();
    superior.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    superior.add(start);
    this.add(superior,"North");

    Panel time = new Panel();
    time.add(timer);
    superior.add(time,"East");

    Panel lett = new Panel();
    lett.add(lettre);
    superior.add(lett,"West");

    Panel central = new Panel();
    central.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));
    this.add(central, "Center");

    central.add(un);
    central.add(deux);
    central.add(trois);
    central.add(quatre);
    central.add(cinq);
    central.add(six);
    central.add(sept);
    central.add(huit);
    central.add(neuf);
    central.add(dix);
    central.add(onze);
    central.add(douze);
    central.add(treize);
    central.add(quatorze);
    central.add(quinze);
    central.add(seize);

    RestartGame();

    score = new Label ("Votre Score est " + scur);
    this.add(score,"South");

    un.addActionListener(this);
    deux.addActionListener(this);
    trois.addActionListener(this);
    quatre.addActionListener(this);
    cinq.addActionListener(this);
    six.addActionListener(this);
    sept.addActionListener(this);
    huit.addActionListener(this);
    neuf.addActionListener(this);
    dix.addActionListener(this);
    onze.addActionListener(this);
    douze.addActionListener(this);
    treize.addActionListener(this);
    quatorze.addActionListener(this);
    quinze.addActionListener(this);
    seize.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
    {
        String lettres ="";// populateStringArray();
        //Button Buton = (Button) event.getSource();
        Button buton = (Button) event.getSource();
        if (buton == start){
            lettres = populateStringArray();
            timer.setText("Let:" + lettres);
            start.setEnabled(false);
            un.setEnabled(true);
            deux.setEnabled(true);      
            trois.setEnabled(true);
            quatre.setEnabled(true);
            cinq.setEnabled(true);
            six.setEnabled(true);
            sept.setEnabled(true);
            huit.setEnabled(true);
            neuf.setEnabled(true);
            dix.setEnabled(true);
            onze.setEnabled(true);
            douze.setEnabled(true);
            treize.setEnabled(true);
            quatorze.setEnabled(true);
            quinze.setEnabled(true);
            seize.setEnabled(true);

        }
        else if ((buton == un)&&(lettres.equals("q"))){ 
            scur++;
            lettres = populateStringArray();
            System.out.println(lettres);
            timer.setText("Lettre:" + lettres);
            score.setText("Score: "+ scur);
        }
        else if ((buton == deux)&&(lettres.equals("w"))){ 
            scur++;
            lettres = populateStringArray();
            System.out.println(lettres);
            timer.setText("Lettre:" + lettres);
            score.setText("Score: "+ scur);
        }
        else if((buton == trois)/*&&(lettres.equals("e"))*/){ 
            scur++;
            lettres = populateStringArray();
            System.out.println(lettres);
            timer.setText("Lettre:" + lettres);
            score.setText("Score: "+ scur);
        }
        else if ((buton == quatre)&&(lettres.equals("r"))){ 
            scur++;
            lettres = populateStringArray();
            System.out.println(lettres);
            timer.setText("Lettre:" + lettres);
            score.setText("Score: "+ scur);
        }
        else if((buton == cinq)&&(lettres.equals("t"))){ 
            scur++;
            lettres = populateStringArray();
            System.out.println(lettres);
            timer.setText("Lettre:" + lettres);
            score.setText("Score: "+ scur);
        }
        else if((buton == six)&&(lettres.equals("y"))){ 
            scur++;
            lettres = populateStringArray();
            System.out.println(lettres);
            timer.setText("Lettre:" + lettres);
            score.setText("Score: "+ scur);
        }
        else if((buton == sept)&&(lettres.equals("u"))){ 
            scur++;
            lettres = populateStringArray();
            System.out.println(lettres);
            timer.setText("Lettre:" + lettres);
            score.setText("Score: "+ scur);
        }
        else if((buton == huit)&&(lettres.equals("i"))){ 
            scur++;
            lettres = populateStringArray();
            System.out.println(lettres);
            timer.setText("Lettre:" + lettres);
            score.setText("Score: "+ scur);
        }
        else if((buton == neuf)&&(lettres.equals("o"))){ 
            scur++;
            lettres = populateStringArray();
            System.out.println(lettres);
            timer.setText("Lettre:" + lettres);
            score.setText("Score: "+ scur);
        }
        else if((buton == dix)&&(lettres.equals("p"))){ 
            scur++;
            lettres = populateStringArray();
            System.out.println(lettres);
            timer.setText("Lettre:" + lettres);
            score.setText("Score: "+ scur);
        }
        else if((buton == onze)&&(lettres.equals("a"))){ 
            scur++;
            lettres = populateStringArray();
            System.out.println(lettres);
            timer.setText("Lettre:" + lettres);
            score.setText("Score: "+ scur);
        }
        else if((buton == douze)&&(lettres.equals("s"))){ 
            scur++;
            lettres = populateStringArray();
            System.out.println(lettres);
            timer.setText("Lettre:" + lettres);
            score.setText("Score: "+ scur);
        }
        else if((buton == treize)&&(lettres.equals("d"))){ 
            scur++;
            lettres = populateStringArray();
            System.out.println(lettres);
            timer.setText("Lettre:" + lettres);
            score.setText("Score: "+ scur);
        }
        else if((buton == quatorze)&&(lettres.equals("f"))){ 
            scur++;
            lettres = populateStringArray();
            System.out.println(lettres);
            timer.setText("Lettre:" + lettres);
            score.setText("Score: "+ scur);
        }
        else if((buton == quinze)&&(lettres.equals("g"))){ 
            scur++;
            lettres = populateStringArray();
            System.out.println(lettres);
            timer.setText("Lettre:" + lettres);
            score.setText("Score: "+ scur);
        }
        else if((buton == seize)&&(lettres.equals("h"))){ 
            scur++;
            lettres = populateStringArray();
            System.out.println(lettres);
            timer.setText("Lettre:" + lettres);
            score.setText("Score: "+ scur);
        }

        //else System.out.println(lettres);
        else {
            lettres = populateStringArray();
            System.out.println(lettres);
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Please reduce the code to the bare minimum to reproduce this issue. Read [MCVE].

Comment: Consider using an array of char instead of String for the variable _num_ such that you will be able to use _lettres == 'q'_

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that lettres is always initialized to an empty string "" anytime this action listener is triggered, therefore the equals() method will always be checking against an empty string. None of the else if statements can ever be true.